# convert string with dots to currency with euro,

Tags: c#, currency

I have a string like this : "44.00000000000"

The dot is decimal point in this case, I am trying to convert to Euro currency. but having problems

Please see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: For financial calculations use `decimal`.

Comment: You seem to be forcing it French culture, where I believe the , would be the decimal point and the . would be a thousand separator.  In this case, your string is invalid.  Why are you forcing the culture in this fashion?

Comment: BTW - the screenshot is very hard to read, and also hard to search on.  Text based snippet of code is much better.

Comment: @Paddy I was just doing tests, all I know is the string after the query comes with a dot. I can remove that line. but that wont make a difference

Comment: @Paddy Unfortunately, I can't see screenshot.

Comment: @Paddy, I can read the screenshot very well if you click on the image it will open big. http://i.stack.imgur.com/o2E6S.png

Comment: Well you need to do something, as this string is not a valid decimal representation in the culture you are using.  Either you need to change how you get the value, or change how you parse it - I can't tell you which is most applicable to your situation.

Comment: @Paddy I removed the line of thread.currentculture and the it converts the 44.000000000 to 4400000000, and the real number should be 44 euros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your decimal parse line to use the following:

```
decimal.Parse(inputString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You may want to have a read around here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx

Comment: I'm in USA.  How could I get the string to be converted into Euro?

Comment: @Auguste - you probably need to expand on what you need an ask it as a question of its own.